# Problems reading my gel electrophoresis result

Tags: plasmids, gel-electrophoresis, ecoli

This is an image of my gel electrophoresis result. [image]

I used the alkaline lysis method to extract E. coli plasmid and put it on gel electrophoresis. Based on what I had learned, I expected to see a band of nicked plasmid, a band of supercoiled plasmid and a smear at the positive end due to DNAse that was not completely removed.

However, I can't identify which band is which in my result and the smear from 200 to 1000bp having 3 bright bands is confusing me.
Could you please help me identify the forms of plasmid present in this result?

Comment: What plasmid are you trying to isolate, which size do you expect?